# How to copy multiple lines to clipboard without an added space to each line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, clipboard

I am able to copy multiple lines of text to clipboard with the help of the following script and it works fine.

```
@echo off
(
echo aaa
echo bbb
echo ccc
)|clip
```

The only problem is that for some reason at the end of each line it also copies a single space which I than have to delete manually.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes.  See this SO Answer. [Prevent extra whitespace when piping data in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47707651/1417694)

Comment: @Squashman the code on that page is very complicated. I could not find solution to problem. Can you please post answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for [Prevent extra whitespace when piping data in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47707651/1417694) explains your problem perfectly.  I will translate those answers to your code.  Essentially there are two of the three code examples you can use since you are not dealing with environmental variables.

1) Add an extra CMD /C where you explicitly get the exact behavior you are looking for

```
cmd /c "echo aaa&echo bbb&echo ccc"|clip
```

3) Introduce delayed expansion of a linefeed variable - a mind blowing technique developed by jeb

```
set ^"LF=^
%= This creates a linefeed character =%
"
(echo aaa%%LF%%echo bbb%%LF%%echo ccc%%LF%%)|clip
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. Due to my low reputation I couldn't upvote your answer but I will try to remember this and upvote it sometime later when I have a higher reputation.